# What are the molecular orbitals shaped like in diberyllium (mono)cation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, orbitals

I think one way of describing the result is that the bond in $\ce{Be^+_2}$? cation is a resonance hybrid of two possible pi bonds. Each pi bond has a bond order of 1 so the resonance hybrid structure has two partial pi bonds. But then can it further be in a resonance hybrid of different rotations and so be an even cylinder?

I guess if you wanted to be silly you could say that that the electron configuration for each beryllium ion is like:

$$ \underset{2s}{[\uparrow \downarrow]} \underset{(2p)^2}{[\uparrow \vert \;]} \underset{2p}{[\;]} $$

Comment: The resonance hybrid of the two pi orientations *does* produce an even cylinder. You don't need to include other rotations.

Comment: @f" Suppose I had two resonant pi orientations such as in carbon dioxide. Can I freely rotate the parts around each other then?

Comment: What do you mean by "freely rotate the parts around each other"? The electron density of the molecule has cylindrical symmetry, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: the molecular orbitals will be $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ and thus cylindrically symmetric.**

First off, your electron configuration is wrong. $\ce{Be2+}$ will have 3 electrons, so the $\ce{2p}$ orbitals need not be considered.

Here's a quick MO diagram:

[image: MO picture for Be2+]

So there aren't an $\pi$ bonds at all. There's a $\sigma$ and a $\sigma^*$ orbital, for a bond order of 0.5.

If I generate orbitals (using [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/)) then I see something like this for the $\sigma$

[image]

And this is the $\sigma^*$

[image]