# Could Be2- exist?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, stability

I understand that Be<sub>2</sub> cannot exist, since it has as many electrons in the antibonding as in the bonding orbitals.

But it seems to me that since the next electron would go into the π<sub>u</sub> orbital, which is a bonding orbital, Be<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup> would have a bond order of 0.5, and Be<sub>2</sub><sup>2-</sup> would have a bond order of 1, since it would have 4 in bonding (2 in σ and 2 in π)and only 2 in the σ*.

Could Be<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup> or Be<sub>2</sub><sup>2-</sup> at least theoretically be produced?  In other words, would the energy released by forming a bond be sufficient to counterbalance the energy needed to stabilize the negative charge gained?

Comment: While it is perfectly fine the way you have formatted your question, we also have MathJax available. If you are curious, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). For the matter at hand, I'd say your reasoning is sound; I wouldn't be too sure about whether one electron is already too much. Anyway, you might find this publication interesting: 10.1126/science.1174326 (it is about the neutral dimer though). Judging from 10.1002/qua.20633, it seems to be stable.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75655/is-be2-diamagnetic https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55497/what-are-the-molecular-orbitals-shaped-like-in-diberyllium-monocation